# Row count in R with Group By

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate a percentage, grouped by a discrete element, in this case win_percentage.  The column I'm calculating off of is favorite_win, which has a 0 or 1 value. I'm able to calculate the numerator easily, since I just want to sum all the 1's in the column.

wins_by_spread <- df %>% group_by(spread_favorite) %>%  summarise(wins = sum(favorite_win))

To get the denominator, I figured getting a row count would be easiest. However, when I try the below code, no values come back.

games_by_spread <- df %>% group_by(spread_favorite) %>%  summarise(games = nrow(favorite_win))

Comment: `nrow` gives the umber of rows of a data frame. Try with `summarise(games = n())` instead which gives the number of observations per `spread_favorite` group. To compute the percentage with one line you could e.g. do `summarise(wins = sum(favorite_win), games = n(), pct = wins / games)`.

Comment: Please provide your data by running `dput(df)` and pasting the output in your question so people can help :)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this gave me what I need, thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Sorry Shawn, I tried putting more detail but SO keeps saying it's spam.  Hard for a newbie to get help on here when the system doesn't let you give the detail.